# How to link C++ to use variable defined in static C library (symbol not found error)

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I have C static library that has a struct global variable defined within it.  I wish to access that variable within C++ code that will link to that C library.  At the moment, I am getting "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" errors.

I am trying the following (simplified struct for the sake of the question):

```
// library.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
  int simpleVariableA;
  int simpleVariableB;
} GlobalStruct;

extern GlobalStruct gs;
#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif

// library.c
#include "library.h"
GlobalStruct gs;
```

Library.c and library.h are compiled into library.a, a statically-linked library.  I then want to link a C++ file to the library, but get errors.

```
// main.cpp
#include "library.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  gs.simpleVariableA = 1;
  gs.simpleVariableB = 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have run "nm -g library.a" and get "0000000000000008 C _gs" back, so I think this means that the symbol is being exported, no?  Is it an issue with C++ not finding C code?

I compile the files like this:

```
gcc -c library.c -o library.o
ar rcs liblibrary.a library.o
g++ main.cpp -L. -llibrary
```

BTW, I get an error with the ar command:

```
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: liblibrary.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

However, this error goes away if I define a function f() in library.h and library.c and compile this into the library.

Comment: Hmm at least it's a warning :/ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your mentions of `gs` is merely a *declaration* (that is it indicates that there is a thing by this name *somewhere*), but none of them is a *definition* (which is something which additionally sets aside space for the named thing).

If you initialise `gs` in `library.c`, your problem goes away:

```
GlobalStruct gs = { 0, 0 };
```

The function of the `extern` keyword in your `library.h` is specifically to *stop* this being a (tentative) definition.  It's possibly redundant in this case, but probably best to include it, and so make sure that there's only one *definition* of `gs`, in `library.c`.

Including the initialiser in `library.c` also stops the warning message, because that initialiser is what creates the thing that goes in the library (that is, you were correct: the warning *was* significant for your problem).

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much.  I didn't realise that not setting a variable to an initial value means it's not actually properly defined, I had thought mentioning it in the .c file meant it was fully defined.

Comment: There's further information about declarations and definitions in [this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/)

Comment: Very nice, thanks very much.  My confusion over the definition is based on the fact that a program will compile if you put "Globalstruct gs;" in the .cpp file, so I have always assumed that that was a sufficient definition.